# Dynamic Time Warping with moving window

Tags: time-series, dtw

I have two time series, lets say **X** and **Y** with 127 and 64 observations in each respectively. I have applied DTW with global constraint to get the distance and then further used that distance to calculate another coefficient. Now I want to calculate DTW using rolling window for the timeseries using one year period for DTW calculations. Lets say, both **X** and **Y** starts on January 2012 but **X** is monthly observation and **Y** is two-monthly observation. This gives that I will have to calculated DTW for **X_1** and **Y_1** with 12 and 6 observations respectively and then will shift the window by 2 months for next DTW distance. Now my problem is that I can not find reference from literature that guides about the minimum number of observations needed for DTW algorithm to give meaningful results